# Autocomplete select option using ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a select and an input. When I select an option the input should load autocomplete data on the value of each option.

```
<select>
    <option class="selectOption" value="1">option 1</option>
    <option class="selectOption" value="2">option 2</option>
    <option class="selectOption" value="3">option 3</option>
    <option class="selectOption" value="4">option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="search">
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you've written yourself to attempt to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean? You want if you select option 3, that "option 3" will automatically appear in the input box?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you need to add selected value in dropdown to input box. Here is my code see if it fits your requirement.
HTML code

```
<select onchange="getval(this);">
    <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
    <option value="option 3">option 3</option>
    <option value="option 4">option 4</option>
</select>
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' value="option 1" />
```

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getval(sel) {
    alert(sel.value);
    var a=sel.value;
    $("#tags").val(a);
    }
</script>
```

and here is the demo link please see is that works as you need.[demo_link](http://jsfiddle.net/fjpz7mxe/)